# Undefined symbol when linking static library to Android NDK

Tags: android, android-ndk, sdl, static-libraries

I'm using a Gradle project provided by the [SDL repository](https://github.com/libsdl-org/SDL) to use with Android builds. On its own, the project builds fine with full access to SDL. But I have a static library that I'm trying to link to this project, which is in charge of the app logic.

My app hierarchy looks like this:

```
app/jni/src/arm64-v8a/libsdl-test-arm64-v8a.a
app/jni/src/armeabi-v7a/libsdl-test-armeabi-v7a.a
app/jni/src/x86/libsdl-test-x86.a
app/jni/src/x86_64/libsdl-test-x86_64.a
app/jni/src/Android.mk
app/jni/src/main.c        // calls appInit, defined by the static library
app/jni/src/sdl-test.h    // declares void appInit();
```

According to what I've learned so far, linking a static library requires you to modify an Android.mk file. Here's mine: https://pastebin.com/qhNCyc0c (the library is written in Zig, hence the otherwise confusing comment)

The error I get from running on Android is this:

```
ld: error: undefined symbol: appInit
>>> referenced by main.c:5 (jni/src/main.c:5)
>>>               /Users/mak/dev/zig/sdl-test/android/android-template/app/build/intermediates/cxx/Debug/29445a3u/obj/local/arm64-v8a/objs-debug/main/main.o:(main)
```

I can confirm that the library has the correct architecture by running `file` on the object file used to create it:

```
libsdl-test-arm64-v8a.a.o: ELF 64-bit LSB relocatable, ARM aarch64, version 1 (SYSV), with debug_info, not stripped
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: Your `main` module appears to lack `LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES := sdl-test`

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I need `LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES` in the main module:

```
LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES := sdl-test
```